# Not same result between Lua function myFunction vs a function returning directly myFunction result, as shown by \showtokens\expandafter

Tags: luatex

I have an issue that surprises me.
I have that LaTeX code :

```latex
\newcommand*{\addEvents}{%
    \showtokens\expandafter{%
        \directlua{tex.print(writeEvents())}%
    }%
}
...
\addEvents
...
```

If I build that code with LuaLatex I get in the compiler output :

```latex
\dateDescription {-302}{1}{north west}{20}{120}{\textbf {-302}\\ bla bla};
```

which is exactly what I want.

If I :

- tweak my Lua function to directly return that piece of text instead of computing it

```lua
function writeEvents()
    return [[\dateDescription {-302}{1}{north west}{20}{120}{\textbf {-302}\\ bla bla};]]
end
```

- remove \showtokens\expandafter :

I get the output I want in the produced PDF.
Which makes me think that my Lua function is doing the right job.

Now if I :

- restore my Lua function that with \showtokens\expandafter was outputting the above text
- remove \showtokens\expandafter

Basically, if I let it do its job without capturing the output :

the \textbf {-302} is missing. It is as if it was skipped.

So in other words I have different results by :

- using a Lua function
  vs
- replacing its result by the result written by \showtokens\expandafter

How could it be?

Comment: Sorry, but you don't show the Lua function you're using, but only the tweaked version, so how can anybody make a comparison? Please, make a full compilable example, stating more clearly what you expect from it.

Comment: Isn't its result that matters? Could it be that \showtokens\expandafter doesn't exactly capture the function result? Apparently that is the case because the PDF is different in both cases. I'll try to come up with an example.

Comment: @FilippoGuenzi Good to hear you solved it. Result matters but Process matters more. Result *X* can be produced by *n* Processes. Diagnosis is faster when the Process is known. Unrelated: to ping a user, use `@`, otherwise they will not know.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I just had to follow the advices of my Lua compiler to put local in front of local variables and rename global ones with a Capital first letter, be it a variable or a method, and it solved everything. Maybe indirectly but it solved it. Hourray !